Why are the two equations equal?
In some book, we can read

$$g(t,r)=\iint_{|z|\leqslant r} (iu_x-u_y)\text{d}x\text{d}y=i\iint_{|z|\leqslant r}(u_x+iu_y)\text{d}x\text{d}y=i\int_0^r\!\!\!\!\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+ỉu_y)\rho\text{d}\rho\text{d}\theta$$
Set $y=r^2$, $\psi(t,y)=g(t,r^2)$; then $\psi_y=g_rr_y=g_r/2r$, so that using our equation, we find
$$\psi_y=\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=r^2}(u_x+iu_y)\frac{\text{d}z}{z}$$

My question is: why $\psi_y=\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=r^2}(u_x+i u_y)\frac{dz}{z}$ ?
My work so far:
$$\psi_y=\frac{i}{2r}\frac{d}{dr}\int_0^{r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+iu_y)\rho d\rho d\theta=\frac{i}{2r}2r\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+iu_y)r^2d\theta=ir^2\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+iu_y)d\theta$$
But
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=r^2}(u_x+iu_y)\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x^2+y^2=r^4}(u_x+iu_y)\frac{dx+idy}{x+iy}\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x^2+y^2=r^4}(u_x+iu_y)(x-iy)\frac{dx+idy}{x^2+y^2}$$
Let $x=r^2\cos\theta, y=r^2\sin\theta$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=r^2}(u_x+iu_y)\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+iu_y)\frac{(r^2\cos\theta-ir^2\sin\theta)(-r^2\sin\theta+ir^2\cos\theta)}{r^4}d\theta\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x+iu_y)id\theta$$
So how can we have $\psi_y=\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=r^2}(u_x+i u_y)\frac{dz}{z}$?

I'm assuming that $u:\mathbb{R}^2\supset\kern-0.7pt\to\mathbb{R}$ with $x$ denoting the first variable and $y$ denoting the second variable when differentiating. I will also be identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ for convenience.
As $y=r^2$ we have that $r=\sqrt{y}$, so
$$\psi(x,y)=g(x,\sqrt{y})=i\int_0^\sqrt{y}\int_0^{2\pi}(\partial_1u(\rho e^{i\theta})+i\partial_2u(\rho e^{i\theta}))\rho\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\rho$$
(I have switched $\mathrm{d}\rho$ and $\mathrm{d}\theta$ from your post as I believe this to be a typo). Consequently, using the chain rule and the FTC we have that
$$\partial_2\psi(x,y)=i\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\int_0^{2\pi}(\partial_1u(\sqrt{y} e^{i\theta})+i\partial_2u(\sqrt{y} e^{i\theta}))\sqrt{y}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=i\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\partial_1u(\sqrt{y} e^{i\theta})+i\partial_2u(\sqrt{y} e^{i\theta}))\,\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
But observe now that we can parametrize the circle $\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{y}$ by
\begin{align*}
[0,2\pi)&\to\partial B_{\sqrt{y}}(0),\\
\theta&\mapsto\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta},
\end{align*}
which has derivative $z\mapsto i\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta}$, so that
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{y}}(\partial_1u(z)+i\partial_2u(z))\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\partial_1u(\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta})+i\partial_2u(\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta}))\frac{i\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta}}{\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=i\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\partial_1u(\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta})+i\partial_2u(\sqrt{y}e^{i\theta}))\,\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
It consequently follows that
$$\partial_2\psi(x,y)=\int_{\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{y}}(\partial_1u(z)+i\partial_2u(z))\,\mathrm{d}z.$$
So in particular, I believe there is an error in the quoted formula, in particular that it should be $\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{y}$ (alternatively $\lvert z\rvert=r$) instead of $\lvert z\rvert=r^2$. Now $\partial_2\psi(x,y^2)$ is, however, equal to the given expression.
